# I'm trying to implement a file download, but all the downloaded files are either corrupted(image) or empty(pdf)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

I'm trying to implement a file download, but all the downloaded files are either corrupted(image) or empty(pdf). What am I doing wrong?

```
axios.post(`/master/api/Download?filename=${rowData.fileName}&&FolderName=${folderName}&&ext=${rowData.fileExtension}`, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        }).then(function(res) {
            var blob = new Blob([res.data], {
                  type: `application/${extension}`,
                });
            saveAs(blob, fileName );
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `axios.get(...)` to get the downloaded files as calling `axios.post` is trying to send data to a server

Comment: @jedi that’s great. Can you mark this as the answer by clicking the check mark next to my answer and it’ll turn green. This way others know this is the solution. Thanks